# Как поместить переменные в txt файл

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть таблица `users' и в ней есть 1 пользователь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю проверку, если логин/пароль подходит мы переходим на следующую страницу
[image]

мне нужно сделать так, что если пользователь успешно входит в аккаунт, то все данные пользователя заносились в 'users_info.txt', может кто подсказать как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком случае можно воспользоваться функцией [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php), записывающей все необходимые данные в указанный файл. Чтобы не перезаписывать каждый раз файл с нуля, нужно применить флаг `FLAG_APPEND`, в целях безопасности, чтобы никто другой не получил доступ к файлу во время записи — `LOCK_EX`.

Итого мы имеем код примерно следующего содержания:

```php
// объявляем $id, $name и $email из скриншота выше
$filename = "users_info.txt";
$content = "${id} ${name} ${email}\n";
// через пробелы, можно через другое, как Вам угодно
// и да, такая форма записи валидна при помощи обработки переменных в двойных кавычках
// подробности здесь: 
// https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

file_put_contents($filename, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```